# this keyword in class method as a function parameter in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

Tried to pass `this` with type in a class method and then try to access it in 2 ways:

1. Create a new JS object and assign a value. (*No Error*)

   {`getName: obj1.getName`} in below code
2. Save it to a new variable(reference) and call it (*Gives Error*)

   `const a = obj1.getName;` in below code

> What is the concept behind these two? When I have defined `this: MyClass` saying it is of type `MyClass` then it should give error for the first one as well.

**typescript** code

```js
class MyClass {
    x:string = "Class value";
    
    getName(this: MyClass) {
        return this.x;
    }
}

// Creating class object
const obj1 = new MyClass();
console.log(obj1.getName());

// Creating JS object
const obj2 = {x: 'Object Value', getName: obj1.getName}

// Will not give error
console.log(obj2.getName());

// Will give error with below line
const a = obj1.getName;
a();
```

**Error:** `The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyClass'.(2684)`

Ref:

- Typescript Documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters

Comment: "*What is the concept behind these two?*" [How does the "this" keyword work, and when should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429) and [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20279484)

Comment: I need the answer for "When I have defined this: MyClass saying it is of type MyClass then it should give error for the first one as well."

Comment: TS doesn't have exact types. It has structural equality. `obj` is structurally compatible with `MyClass`, therefore the type fits. [What is structural typing?](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-structural-typing)

Comment: Yes this is right. I have found the root cause. Please find the answer below. Appreciate your time in following up. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the above code `obj2` has same signature/definition as `MyClass` thats why it consider that object as an instance of class `MyClass` and hence didn't give error.

While in second case it has different signature and hence typescript gave error.

If we try to create obj2 with x as a number, then signature gets different and it will give error:

### Example:

```
const obj2 = {x: 123, getName: obj1.getName}
```

Error: `The 'this' context of type '{ x: number; getName: (this: MyClass) => string; }' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyClass'`

### Another example:

```js
class MyClass {
    x:string = "Class value";
    
    getName(this: MyClass) {
        // Now returning a string directly removing reference.
        return 'Hello';
    }
}
const obj1 = new MyClass();
console.log(obj1.getName());

// Creating JS object
const obj2 = {x: 3, getName: obj1.getName}

// Will now give error
console.log(obj2.getName());
```

**Error:**

```
The 'this' context of type '{ x: number; getName: (this: MyClass) => string; }' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'MyClass'.
  Types of property 'x' are incompatible.
    Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2684)
```